# Beamer \usefonttheme{professionalfonts} for Windows fonts, text editing commands ignored

Tags: beamer, fonts, xetex

I'm having some problems with text edition (boldface, italics, ...) in beamer compilation. The issue began when I started using professional fonts instead of default ones.

Typsetting with "XeLaTeX + MakeIndex + BibTeX"

```
\usefonttheme{professionalfonts}               % using non standard fonts for beamer
\usefonttheme{serif}                           % default family is serif
\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Cambria Math}                     % Windows font
```

When using commands like `\textit{bla bla bla}` or `\textbf{bla bla bla}` or `\emph{bla bla bla}`, they're just ignored.

Thank you, fellas!

Comment: I'm neither on windows, nor do I have Cambria Math installed, but the name sounds like a math font. I wouldn't be surprised if it does not have bold or serif. Try with just normal `Cambria` instead...